# Is this rebook/more button in my UI in the right place?

Tags: gui-design, mobile-application

I'm worried that it is taking up too much real-estate at the moment - and the massive gap besides the button that can be used for something else or perhaps be made **less** apparent.

What do you think? Would appreciate any design cues!

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just make a couple of mockups and test from there?

Comment: I would put the button on a detail screen for the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern on touch devices is to be able to slide an item to reveal action buttons. Sometimes there's a lot of options, sometimes just one.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Seamless iPhone app has a similar UI. I like that the "reorder" button is next to each list item and not hidden. I only wish the reorder button were taller and wider.

Answer (score 0):

On a mobile device it might benefit from a bigger button, perhaps having the button span nearly full width will solve the visual imbalance issue you are bringing up.

If we're only looking at adjusting the design according to the current button size, I'd try centering the button to reduce the gap. It's also interesting to think about which side the button is floating towards to, people holding and using the device with only the left hand might have some trouble tapping some buttons with the thumb.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a primary action, it seems very convenient to place it on the current screen instead of hiding it and asking a user to discover it behind a gesture or on a separate page.

The most visually pleasing or clever layout to designers is not always the best choice for the customer. I can say this from experience and learning the hard way.

If you wanted to balance the buttons, you could make it full width or you could expand the overflow button (...) to a normal button and position it next to rebook. There are a lot of solutions for this, while still maintaining the primary action on screen.

Personally, I'd move to hi-fi mocks to address that issue.